# REGEX in Python: Referring to characters at start of text

Tags: python, regex

I'm having trouble coming up with the regex statement to reference this: `10/03/2006 09:38:37` at the beginning of every line. I've tried for a couple hours. I'm not good with regex. Figured I'd ask for help on here. Below is what I came up with so far:

```
searchObj_Archive_date = re.search(r'^\d{2}.?d{2}.?d{4}s?d{2}\.?\d{2}\.?\d{2}', line, re.M|re.I)'
```

Comment: post all the valid formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex  `^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}` matches your string, but you may need to provide additional formats (for instance, I notice that in your sample regex you are not requiring forward slashes between the numbers in your date or colons between the elements of the time - was that intentional?).

Comment: Good deal. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @pHorseSpec If you need to do more regexes, this site will be your friend: https://regex101.com/#python

Answer (score 1):

You're not escaping some of the decimal (`\d`) and whitespace (`\s`) specifiers and you *are* escaping the fullstop which gives a literal fullstop instead of a match all character. I would suggest using the actual characters for the separators instead of a generic match all anyway:

```
r'^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\s?\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}'
```